# Add character to variable in Loop

Tags: python

I have several lists: values1, values2, values3.

Now I want to do some operations in a loop. I was looking for an easy solution without using dictionaries to do something like this:

```
values1 = []
values2 = []
values3 = []

for i in numpy.arange(1, 3):
    items = values+str(i)
    ...
    ...
```

Is there a quick an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend)

Comment: What's wrong with doing `for items in (values1, values2, values3):`? BTW, you should give those lists more meaningful names. Using a series of numbered names is an anti-pattern, and generally indicates that the objects in question should be in a list or tuple.

Comment: Didnt think about that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
values1 = []
values2 = []
values3 = []

for values in [values1, values2, values3]:
    ...
```